# Learning Stochastic Processing, Modeling, and Analysis: Any Available Workbooks?

Tags: soft-question, stochastic-processes, book-recommendation

Motivation behind the question: I took the upper-level probability course at my college, and did pretty well. Most of the time throughout the class, I found myself intuitively understanding the material more so than I have in other courses. After speaking with my advisor, I signed up for the college's course on stochastic processes.

It was a nightmare- they dumped all the undergrads into a class designed exclusively for graduate students who've taken prerequisites that UG's did not. Every undergrad was doing miserably in the course, and my advisor later conceded that it wasn't an appropriate course to offer to UG's- but hey, it was the next course after probability to study uncertainty!

I still have my textbooks from the course: Mikosch's *Elementary Stochastic Calculus*, and Lawler's *Introduction to Stochastic Processes*. I get the impression they're really good textbooks, and I've tried working through some of the chapters. Nevertheless, I find myself wanting to do more problems; I guess I learn really well by practicing problems, and get comfortable with any material by working through many examples.

Can anyone recommend a suitable stochastic processes workbook, preferably with a solution section in the back? I'd eventually like to apply stochastic analysis to areas in finance, engineering, economics, etc. when I look to enter the job market. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should probably try to get at least a feel for general measure theory, even if you can't do problems, before trying to learn stochastic processes. In probability the measure-theoretic machinery is easy to hide, but in stochastic processes this is just not true. Note that if you do so, for probability applications you can safely ignore the caveats on theorems that don't hold in infinite measure spaces. From a probabilist's perspective, these all boil down to "you can't put a uniform distribution on the whole real line".

Comment: Thanks @Ian. In the meantime, I also have Gerald Edgar's *Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry*. Do you think a text like that would help one get a feel for measure theory?

Comment: Perhaps; I'm not familiar with the text, though it sounds more broad than I intended. In particular, the title suggests to me that a major goal of that text will be to define Hausdorff measure and Hausdorff dimension, which while interesting is not very instructive for the study of stochastic processes.

Comment: (Cont.) I had in mind Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick, in particular the second half or so where they handle general measure theory. I really came to understand measure theory using this book (though it may have helped to have one of the authors teaching the course).

Comment: The Leon-Garcia undergrad probability book _Probability, Statistics, and Random Processes for Electrical Engineering_ has later chapters on stochastic processes, including Markov chains.  A good grad text on stochastic processes is Bob Gallager's _Discrete Stochastic Processes_.  I do not recommend measure theory at this stage, unless you are interested in foundations. That is like requiring students to read Russell's _Principia Mathematica_ before doing basic arithmetic.